# How can I create custom graphs with python to export as an image to latex?

Tags: python, graph, latex

How can I create custom graphs like this in python?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Matplotlib

Matplotlib is the go-to python library for visualization. Check out tutorials on their website: https://matplotlib.org/

Sidenote: For a simple plot like this, you could look into latex plotting/graphing tools like pgfplots https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/pgfplots_package